# Unassigned Variable error but its Assigned

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been making a patrolling AI that goes left and right on a platform and uses an invisible laser that checks if the ground still exists on the platform, now I encountered an issue with the console that spams the message of the variable not being assigned, https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0i6C.jpg This image will help you understand whats going on better.

I tried unassigning, restarting, removing the script entirely, nothing really worked.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PatrollingAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    private bool movingRight = true;

    public Transform groundCheck;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        RaycastHit2D groundInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(groundCheck.position, Vector2.down, 2f);
        if (groundInfo.collider == false)
        {
            if (movingRight == true)
            {
                transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, -180, 0);
                movingRight = false;
            }
            else
            {
                transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                movingRight = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The message is supposed to not show up.

Comment: You are accessing groundCheck.position (RaycastHit2D groundInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(groundCheck.position, Vector2.down, 2f)), but the groundCheck value is probably not initialised (null reference).

Comment: Create a `Start` method and in it do a `null` check on the `groundCheck Transform`and if it is null print out `Debug.Log(gameObject.name)` to check the `gameObject` by name in the scene to make sure it is set in the editor

Comment: before your raycasting add `if (!groundCheck) Debug.LogError("groundCheck not set!", this);`. Then when this message is shown you can simply click on it in the console and it should highlight the object where it is thrown.

Comment: @derHugo it highlights my only enemy that i've set with this script

Comment: UnassignedReferenceException: The variable groundCheck of PatrollingAI has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the groundCheck variable of the PatrollingAI script in the inspector.
UnityEngine.Transform.get_position () <0x42a1c240 + 0x0006a> in <a3576e8393954d35950f38fbe0f61f49>:0
PatrollingAI.Update () (at F:/Unity/Projects/New Unity Project (2)/Assets/PatrollingAI.cs:16)

Comment: thats the error it tells me

Comment: do you assign `groundCheck` via the Inspector before starting the play mode? Or is it done somewhere else dynamically?

Comment: I assigned groundCheck Exactly to where it was supposed to be in the inspector
aka public transform groundCheck;